# Why if a in a|b crashes, b may not receive all already produced output from a

Tags: bash

Consider `a | b` executed in bash, if `a` does `Segmentation fault`, `b` (for instance `cat`) may only get partial data. I tried this with many processes, the behavior is not stable, once in a while you get entire output of `a`, but most of the time it is truncated, i.e. last 5-10 lines are not shown. At the same time, if you run only `a`, no pipe, just output to terminal, all data is always there displayed in the terminal.

Here is the question, why is this happening, and how to ensure the right most process (`b`) gets all data that leftmost (`a`) was able to produce before it crashed.

Let's assume I can modify both programs source code.

In my case I had used programs written in C and in Node.js, the behaviour stands for both languages, so I am not sure which use in a tag and will it be relevant to tag in `C` or `Nodejs`.

Comment: Does `a` ever segfault when you *aren't* running it in a pipe? Also, this sounds like it could be an issue with `a` producing buffered output when it is connected to the pipe vs. unbuffered output when writing to the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in glibc, stdout is 'line-buffered' (writes happened at the end of lines) when attached to a terminal, and 'fully-buffered' (writes happen when the buffer is full) otherwise (for instance when attached to a pipe).

As the buffer size for pipes is often from 4kB to 64kB, a lot more of the output of `a` is buffered before it is fed into `b` than if it were written to the terminal.

To unbuffer the output of `a` when attached to a pipe, you can use one of [these techniques](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe):

- the `expect` command `unbuffer`
- `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 command`
- `socat`